# How soon should i reapply for a standard visitor visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens

I was denied a Uk visa because the consular stated that i want to use 80% of the money i have in my Account and at such the visa was denied. What do i do to reapply and how soon should i reapply

Comment: Be aware Nigerians have among the highest visa refusal rates for the UK. Basically the deck is already stacked against you from the outset. So you better have all bases covered. Your chances are already slim, with one refusal it is slimmer.

Answer (score 4):

The way to reapply is to file a new application from scratch.

In principle you can do that as soon as you have your passport back. There is no mandatory waiting period.

**However** -- as the refusal letters themselves point out -- if the reason why your first application was denied *still applies* when you apply again, you will just be refused again. That's a waste of money, and the more refusals you accumulate, the more suspicion will *future* applications be treated with,

So the *meaningful* time to apply again is not before your circumstances have changed such that you're not an illegal-immigration risk.